# Beside the Sage Advice, are there other official documents listing the errata?

Tags: dnd-5e, errata

At [this page](https://dnd.wizards.com/sage-advice/book-updates) and in the PDF document of the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2020/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) one can find the list of official errata of some manuals.

However, in a [recent Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/207002/63061) we found that *not all the modifications* are listed in these errata: for example, the wording on opportunity attacks in PHB have been modified without been mentioned anywhere, to the best of my knowledge.

Are there any other official documents that show a complete list of errata of the manuals?

Comment: Heavily related: [As of the November 2018 core book updates, what changes were made in the latest printings of the PHB that aren't noted in the errata document?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/150613/41726)

Comment: @DavidCoffron Completely missed that, thanks!

Comment: Found this blog post, if it's helpful. https://thinkdm.org/5e-errata/

Comment: @JoJoYawson It seems to me that collects all the things that are already in the SAC, or am I wrong?